# How to avoid large list error when modifying URL filtered view

Tags: filter, view, url, large-lists

I have run into a problem with SharePoint that is frustrating my users to no end. I have a large list (>5000 rows) that users can arrive at by clicking links formatted like this

```
http://my.farm.com/mfg/MySite/Lists/PLOT%20Compliance%20Exception/OpenIssues.aspx?FilterField1=Area&FilterValue1=DRY%20ETCH
```

However once they click on that and get to the view, they are not able to add any more filter options manually. If they click on a column (all the columns are indexed) header they get a cryptic error message like this:

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904<br/><br/>Correlation ID:abc5ef9c-08bb-d0a2-a96a-efc6c7c0418d<br/>
```

However, if I visit the same base view (show below) without any filters in the URL I can then manually add all the filters that were in the previous URL. The base view always returns < 5000 rows so the large list limit shouldn't affect it.

```
http://my.farm.com/mfg/MySite/Lists/PLOT%20Compliance%20Exception/OpenIssues.aspx
```

Is there any way to craft a URL that will filter the view AND allow the user to modify it further without triggering errors?

Comment: Are they trying to add filters to the column "Area" or is it any column? Have you tried to access the same url as a sitecollection administrator?

Comment: You should check the correlation ID in the logs

Comment: I am an SCE and get the same errors. I don't think I have access to the logs, but I'll ask around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this by adding this to the link

```
#InplviewHashfda8118a-f32f-48f1-8782-f48da3428ba7=
```

With causes SharePoint to remember the settings as the user adds more filters, where fda8118a-f32f-48f1-8782-f48da3428ba7 is the list id. So a complete url would be

```
http://my.farm.com/mfg/TrecMan/Lists/PLOT%20Compliance%20Exception/OpenIssues.aspx#InplviewHashfda8118a-f32f-48f1-8782-f48da3428ba7=FilterFields1%3DStatus-FilterValues1%3DAssigned%253B%2523Created-FilterField2%3DArea-FilterValue2%3DWET%2520PROCESS
```

If I remember correctly the parameters also needed to be double encoded which made things extra annoying.